# Sum Values Associated with a String

Tags: python, loops

I am using Python to play around with a CSV file. I am trying to create a  loop that will return values associated with the strings in the first column. Specifically, for every row that contains the string "string" I would like the values of column 2 to be summed. I have many rows of data that contain the string "string", and I would like every value of the second column associated with the string "string" summed to give me one single number.

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
             Column1                         Column2                     Column 3
9           NaN                        40                      101

12        String                        50                      102
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the correct output for the example you have would be 76.42 is this correct.  Also what format are the files in can we simple `cat` the file out.

Comment: Oh that is alot easier simple cat the file into grep then awk the fourth field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly encourage you to look into [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Its `pd.read_csv()` is second to none (IMO) in terms of speed and features. And then, you get pretty awesome analytics capabilities.

Anyway, for your question, there are many ways you can approach that. Here is one:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df.loc[df['Shadow'] == 'Full Shadow', 'February'].sum()
# gives: 35.37
```

Or, to give you a taste of cool things you can do in one line of pandas:

```py
df.groupby('Shadow').sum()
```

Gives:

```
             February  March
Shadow                      
Full Shadow     35.37  41.05
No Record       26.60  39.97
```

Comment: Thank you, I am familiar with pandas. I really appreciate your response, this is exactly what I was looking for. You the man!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python, this might help you.
I assume you are using Excel to store the values, so what you need to do is:
First get the openpyxl package `pip install openpyxl` install into your python

```
import json
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook(filename='C:/Users/john/Desktop/fjdc.xlsx')
sheet = workbook["sheet1"]

sum = 0

# Using the values_only because you want to return the cells' values
# whatever the min and max col you want
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=0,
                           min_col=0,
                           max_col=3,
                           values_only=True):
 if(row[0]=="Full_Shadow"):
   sum+=float(row[1])

# Using json here to be able to format the output for displaying later
print(json.dumps(sum))
```